# JQuery long delay on .scrollTop() calculation

Tags: jquery, delay, scrolltop

I wrote this little bit of code to calculation the distance to the top of the page. Depending if the distance is 0 or not it make a an image disappear/appear and moves the secondary have on up/down.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#headerImg').animate({height:'0px'}, 500);
        $('#wrapperSCNav').animate({top:'185px'}, 500);
    } else {
        $('#headerImg').animate({height:'290px'}, 500);
        $('#wrapperSCNav').animate({top:'475px'}, 500);
    }
});
```

Which kinda works, I'm pretty sure the problem is that code is calculating scrollTop() so many times that it takes it's self seconds to realize that its back at 0.

Comment: You're calling the animate function every step of the scroll phase. Especially in browsers with smooth scrolling enabled this'll be extremely heavy on the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider throttling the scrolling function, such that it fires after a set interval rather that many dozen times a second. I have always recommended using [Ben Alman's plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/).

The modification to your code will be quite minimal - in the code below, I have chosen to throttle the scroll event such that it fires every 250ms (or 4 times per second). You can of course adjust this value.

```
$(window).scroll($.throttle(250, function(){ // Use $.throttle() before calling function
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#headerImg').animate({height:'0px'}, 500);
        $('#wrapperSCNav').animate({top:'185px'}, 500);
    } else {
        $('#headerImg').animate({height:'290px'}, 500);
        $('#wrapperSCNav').animate({top:'475px'}, 500);
    }
})); // Extra closing parenthesis from $.throttle()
```

---

On a side note, it is also probably a good idea to forcibly clear the animation queue and jump to end state before you fire each animation using `.stop(true,true)`:

```
$(window).scroll($.throttle(250, function(){ // Use $.throttle() before calling function
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#headerImg').stop(true,true).animate({height:'0px'}, 500);
        $('#wrapperSCNav').stop(true,true).animate({top:'185px'}, 500);
    } else {
        $('#headerImg').stop(true,true).animate({height:'290px'}, 500);
        $('#wrapperSCNav').stop(true,true).animate({top:'475px'}, 500);
    }
})); // Extra closing parenthesis from $.throttle()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will help:

This will only apply the changes after the user has stopped scrolling.

```
var timer;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout( refresh , 150 );
});
var refresh = function () { 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#headerImg').animate({height:'0px'}, 500);
        $('#wrapperSCNav').animate({top:'185px'}, 500);
    } else {
        $('#headerImg').animate({height:'290px'}, 500);
        $('#wrapperSCNav').animate({top:'475px'}, 500);
    }        
};
```

**Update**

Or if you would like it only to change when scrolling but only when needed:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0 && $('#headerImg').height() != 0) {
        $('#headerImg').animate({height:'0px'}, 500);
        $('#wrapperSCNav').animate({top:'185px'}, 500);
    } else if($('#headerImg').height() == 0) {
        $('#headerImg').animate({height:'290px'}, 500);
        $('#wrapperSCNav').animate({top:'475px'}, 500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/zzn4g/)***

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('#headerImg').stop().animate({height:'0px'}, 500);
    $('#wrapperSCNav').stop().animate({top:'185px'}, 500);
 } else {
    $('#headerImg').stop().animate({height:'290px'}, 500);
    $('#wrapperSCNav').stop().animate({top:'475px'}, 500);
 }
});
```

**$.fx is filling up**

Every time there is a call to animate, an event with a timeout is pushed into the `fx` queue of the jQuery object for the given selector. When an animation is tied to scrolling, what will occur is that this `fx` queue fills up quickly with these animation callbacks. Scrolling to the bottom and then back, and repeating will cause the animation to have undesired results (most of the time) because it causes everything to wait for every animation to complete before doing the next step.

**use `stop` to prevent it**

The common fix for this is to call [jQuery's `stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) on the jQuery object before using animate. This essentially `pop`s the previous callbacks from the `fx` queue allowing the current animation to run instantly.